# Why isn't my question being answered?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I spent about ½ an hour writing a question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141961/rephrase-spirograph-code-into-function), but I haven't been able to get any answers in nearly 24 hours! Normally, I get an answer to any question almost immediately, and if I don't, I get down votes or comments indicating that it's a bad question. That's why I'm confused now, I've read a few of the guides over to make sure it's a good question, and I can't figure out what's wrong with it. Is my question too long? Also, is it appropriate to make edits to it to try to move it to the top of the active topics in an attempt to get more views?

Comment: Yes, it is, thanks for pointing that out. Should I delete the question @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå

Comment: Just click the "this solved my problem" button.

Comment: Be patient!  It is the weekend, and in the US it is a rather special Sunday. A) it is a tad long B) Personally, I skip **all** questions that basically require me to watch a video to understand the problem or  crossmatch the code to the video to find the error(s). C)`Can someone point me in the right direction?` is not a good question and not what SO does - we don't do hints, nudges, suggestions, ideas, guidance etc.  We do **answers**.  Its otherwise rather well written as evidenced by the UVs.

Comment: Only twenty-four hours?  Pffffff.  [My question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29879140/2792531) hasn't been answered in two weeks.

Comment: Well, @nhgrif no one wants to answer your question. :-P

Comment: @bluefeet I know.  :(  I was just hoping for some meta-effect?

Comment: And [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926759/how-can-i-disable-the-dimming-of-the-code-completion-popup-in-intellij) didn't get a good answer in almost two weeks :-(

Comment: @JonasCz yikes. I need my answer before Wednesday.

Comment: @LukeTaylor you may or may not get an answer by then

Comment: If it's really necessary, you can currently offer up to 150 reps in bounty on your question.

Comment: Yeah. I might offer 100

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many reasons why that (or any) question may remain without answers:

- It could use some tags to give it more visibility (e.g.: graphic, spirographic);
- It may need social media/blogs to make it more public;
- It was asked during a weekend and probably SO has more visitors during weekdays;
- It's too long, and people don't like to read;
- Users don't know what a spirograph is and skip the question;
- It may require more code so it's a minimal, complete, and verifiable example;
- The planets aligned at the moment you click on "Ask question", and it will never get an answer...

Knowing exactly which one applies to this question is probably impossible. On the bright side, you are on the way to get the [Tumbleweed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed) badge :)

Comment: Ooh, I want that badge! Quick, nobody answer my question!

Comment: I was so disappointed when I got it. I still have the question there, probably should delete it

Comment: For this question, the thing that stopped me from making any progress was the lack of a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Note that it does not have to include graphics. A single example of a calculation of a new location for a point that does not give the expected result is enough.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Improving the question would be more constructive than deleting it.

Comment: Doesn't the Tumbleweed badge only apply to questions that aren't voted on, and have no comments?

Comment: According to the [wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions), the Tumbleweed badge is awarded to a question that "after its first week of existence has score of 0, no answers, no comments and no more than 60 views".